# how to load an associative array

Tags: php, json

expected json

```
[
{
 "oV":"myfirstvalue",
 "oT":"myfirsttext"
 },
 {
 "oV":"mysecondvalue",
 "oT":"mysecondtext"
 }
]
```

I am trying to make an associative array by loading data from arrays `myfirsttext[]` and `myfirstvalue[]` instead of real stringsiam getting these from the arrays. I have tried the following, but fails; the expectedJSON is above

```
for($d=0;$d<4;$d++){
  $data = array(
   (object)array(
     'oV' => myfirstvalue[$d],
     'oT' => myfirsttext[$d],
    ),
  );
}
```

assist please

Comment: The `(object)` is not required, and you keep overwriting the `$data`

Comment: And you didn't see any notices when you run your code? Add `error_reporting(-1)` at the top of of your script.

Answer (score 4):

If `myfirsttext` and `myfirsttext` are arrays, do reference like this: `$myFirstValue` and `$myFirsttext`.

Also you were overwriting `$data` every loop.

```
$data = array();
for ($d = 0; $d < 4; $d++) {
    $data[] = array('oV' = > $myfirstvalue[$d], 'oT' = > $myfirsttext[$d]);
}
```

**Update**

Then to get it in javascript, use `json_encode`:

```
<script>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value.oV, value.oT);
});
</script>
```

Or use ajax:

```
<script>
jQuery.getJSON('/somefile.php', function(data) {    
    jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
        console.log(value.oV, value.oT);
    });
});
</script>
```

Where **somefile.php** would look like this:

```
...
$data = array();
for ($d = 0; $d < 4; $d++) {
    $data[] = array('oV' = > $myfirstvalue[$d], 'oT' = > $myfirsttext[$d]);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: how can i retrieve this in jquery.looping it.

Comment: Do i then just have to json_encode it or pass it as it is to js script

Comment: Depends on the situation. If you need the array in all your js, you can just add it to your `<head>`. Otherwise you might want to retrieve it using ajax (`jQuery.getJSON`).

Comment: can't i retrieve it like so:

Comment: can't i retrieve it like so: ....url: 'post_file.php',function work(i,f,response){$.each(response, function(index, value) {
      //console.log(value.oV, value.oT);
    alert(value.UN,value.ON);
  });.....But iam not getting any alerts

Comment: can't i retrieve it like so: ....url: 'post_file.php',function work(i,f,response){$.each(response, function(index, value) { //console.log(value.oV, value.oT); alert(value.UN,value.ON); });.....But iam not getting any alerts – user3253289 just now  edit

Answer (score 0):

You keep overwriting the `$data`. Try this:

```
$data = array();
for($d=0;$d<4;$d++){
  $data[] = array(
     'oV' => $myfirstvalue[$d],
     'oT' => $myfirsttext[$d],
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's simply to convert json string to stdObject or array.

```
    $json = '[
          {
        "oV":"myfirstvalue",
        "oT":"myfirsttext"
        },
        {
        "oV":"mysecondvalue",
        "oT":"mysecondtext"
        }
        ]';

       //jsonArray: 
       $array = json_decode($json, true);

        //stdObject
        $json_stdObj = json_decode($json);
        echo "<pre>";print_r($json_stdObj );exit;
```

//Output[stdClass Object]

```
   Array
    (
     [0] => stdClass Object
       (
        [oV] => myfirstvalue
        [oT] => myfirsttext
       )

     [1] => stdClass Object
       (
        [oV] => mysecondvalue
        [oT] => mysecondtext
       )
    )
```